# Creating dataframes in lapply function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, rvest

I am working on Rvest for web scraping.
I have collected the list of outputs from the page but my functions fails to wrap it in dataframe.
My code:

```
test_qry <- lapply(paste0('https://......&CurrentPage=', 1:3),
             function(url){
               c(
                hospital <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                   html_nodes(".findcompare-results table th.fctitle a") %>% 
                   html_text(),
                Tele_no <- url %>% read_html() %>%
                   html_nodes(".findcompare-results table td p.fctel") %>%
                   html_text())
               
             })
```

I dont know how to create dataframe inside the function to wrap all the variables. I used this function to read all the pages(totally 3 pages).
My output is like this

```
1 Coulsdon Dental Practice 
2 mydentist, Chipstead Valley Road, Coulsdon
3 Coulsdon Dental Clinic 
4 Ivory 
5 Crossways Dental Practice 
6 Confidental Clinic 
7 Azenabor, Ify 
8 Kerschbaumer, Andreas 
9 Paice, Andrew 
10 Kenley Dental Practice
11 Tel: 020 8668 2607
12 Tel: 02086686870
13 Tel: 020 8660 3308
14 Tel: 020 8668 2579
15 Tel: 01737 551622
16 Tel: 020 8660 8923
17 Tel: 01737 554177
18 Tel: 020 8660 0415
19 Tel: 020 8660 6565
20 Tel: 020 8668 2696
```

But I need two seperate variables, it writes to single list.
Like data.frame(name,tele_no)

I have used unlist(test_qry) to create data frame.

Help me please!!!

Comment: So, what is the logic to extract word? Will it always last three word like `Just waking up`

Comment: @harun24hr No it changes, totally 12-time intervals, like this - Just wake up, For breakfast, Mid-morning break, other time in morning, Lunchtime etc...

Comment: Can you put screenshot of some data and expected output. Better share an sample sheet via google drive or dropbox.

Comment: If you want help with this then you will need to post a a more-detailed description of the rules you want to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `tidyverse` along with `tibble()` and `bind_row()` to create df.

Here's a reference:

[Scraping webpage with react JS in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536339/scraping-webpage-with-react-js-in-r/51637923#51637923)