# rvest: Collecting page numbers from a website

Tags: r, rvest

I have the following code to try and scrape a website:

```
url = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/casas/madrid-capital/todas-las-zonas/l"

x <- GET(url)

x %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="App"]/div[2]/div[1]/main/div/div[4]')
```

What I would like to do is collect the page numbers at the bottom of the page, previously the following worked `html_nodes(".sui-PaginationBasic-item a")` however, now it does not. I have tried to put the `xpath` using inspect element.

The output would be something like:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 101)
```

Depending on how many pages are on tis given page.

Comment: Hovering over the pagination buttons reveals a consistent URL pattern www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/viviendas/madrid-capital/todas-las-zonas/l/`n`, where `n` is the page from 1 to currently 200. Harvest with your method of choice. Mind that the server might just block you from firing automated requests.

Comment: Thanks! I just need to determine what the max `n` is - For each region the max `n` will be different.

Comment: Are you getting a captcha response?

Comment: No, I can access the website from the browser without problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I know too little about the details but from this post it seems you might have to take the extra step to simulate visiting with a webbrowser using {RSelenium}: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51541800/18309711

Comment: Just keep incrementing the page until you generate an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RSelenium` we can get the page numbers from pagination by,

```
    library(stringr)
    library(RSelenium)
    library(dplyr)

#launching browser 
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
url = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/casas/madrid-capital/todas-las-zonas/l"
remDr$navigate(url)

#accept cookie
    remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
    
#scroll to the end of page
    webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "html")
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key="end"))
    
#use the up_arrow to get pagination into view
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "up_arrow"))
#get page url from pagination  
    link = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.re-Pagination') %>%  html_nodes('a') %>% 
      html_attr('href')
#extract only page numbers from urls
    str_extract(link, "[[:digit:]]+")
    [1] NA    "2"   "3"   "4"   "200" "2"
```

Comment: Thanks! but what is `remDr` - it is not defined previously.

Comment: Modified the answer